# Sequência de Fibonacci não funciona

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estou com problema na saída da sequência de Fibonacci e não consigo identificar onde está o erro. Aqui vai o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int i, Fib[100], n;

scanf("%d",&n);

printf("0 ");

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){

    if(i == 0){
    Fib[i]=0;
    }
    if(i==1 || i==2){
        Fib[i] = 1;
    }
    else{
        Fib[i] = Fib[i-1] + Fib[i-2];
    } 
}

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    printf("%d ",Fib[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O segundo bloco condicional estava incorreto, pois caso a variável `i` fosse diferente de 1 ou 2 entraria no `else`, por isso Fib[0] estava errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i, Fib[100], n;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            Fib[i] = 0;
        } 
        else if(i == 1 || i == 2){
            Fib[i] = 1;
        }
        else{
            Fib[i] = Fib[i-1] + Fib[i-2];
        }
        printf("Fib[%d] = %d \n", i, Fib[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, me ajudou muito a entender o que estava errado

Answer (score 7):

O motivo de ter errado é que a lógica está complexa demais. Se seguir a definição de Fibonacci fica mais simples.

A definição fala que a sequência começa com 0 e 1, então comece a sequência com 0 e 1 explicitamente. Depois disso não precisar tratar nada, não precisa condicionar o que vai fazer. Fica mais simples e mais rápido.

A definição não fala em uma sequência que tem exceções em determinados elementos. Defina o problema corretamente e a solução sai mais fluida.

Mantive o *array* porque poderia ser uma exigência, mas ele é completamente desnecessário para apenas imprimir uma sequência de Fibonacci.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int fib[100];
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    n--;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", fib[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yLSQJp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/owjzpyfc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Fibonacci.c).

Comment: Obrigado!! Melhorou bem o código mesmo

Answer (score 3):

Você pode trabalhar com o tipo `unsigned long long` que possui tamanho de `64bits`, possibilitando gerar sequencias fibonacci de até `91` números:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_FIBO_SEQ   (91)

typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;  /* ( (2^64) - 1 ) = 18.446.744.073.709.551.615 max. */

int fibonacci( uint64_t f[], int n )
{
    int i = 0;

    if( n <= 0 )
        return -1;

    if( n > MAX_FIBO_SEQ )
        n = MAX_FIBO_SEQ;  /* Nao permite overflow */

    f[0] = 1;

    if( n == 1 )
        return n;

    f[1] = 1;

    if( n == 2 )
        return n;

    for( i = 2; i < n; i++ )
        f[i] = f[i - 2] + f[i - 1];

    return n;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    uint64_t seq[ MAX_FIBO_SEQ ];

    /* Preenche array 'seq' com uma sequencia dos 'n' primeiros
       numeros da serie de Fibonacci... */
    n = fibonacci( seq, n );

    /* Exibe array */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf("%s%lld", (i)?", ":"", seq[i] );
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Teste #1:

```
$ ./fibo 10
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

Teste #2:

```
$ ./fibo 91
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050, 3416454622906707, 5527939700884757, 8944394323791464, 14472334024676221, 23416728348467685, 37889062373143906, 61305790721611591, 99194853094755497, 160500643816367088, 259695496911122585, 420196140727489673, 679891637638612258, 1100087778366101931, 1779979416004714189, 2880067194370816120, 4660046610375530309
```